# why does draw() in xna require a tint parameter

Tags: c#, xna

the spritebatch.draw takes a texture, a rectangle, and a color.

the color is the tint.

Why is the tint necessary? and Why does passing white as the parameter indicate no tint? Why not black, or pass no parameter for tint at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tint color is multiplied on the texture color. White is basically 1 in all channels that keeps original colors unchanged. 
This blog has a comprehensive explanation. 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2009/11/10/premultiplied-alpha-in-xna-game-studio.aspx